# Passing by reference and value in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, reference, linked-list

I'm doing a question from LeetCode. I've found something that doesn't make much sense to me.

The question:

> Given a linked list, swap every two adjacent nodes and return its
>   head.
>
> For example, Given 1->2->3->4, you should return the list as
>   2->1->4->3.
>
> Your algorithm should use only constant space. You may not modify the
>   values in the list, only nodes itself can be changed.

My solution:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def swapPairs(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """

        dummy = ListNode(0)
        dummy.next = head
        curr = dummy

        while curr.next and curr.next.next:
            a = curr.next
            b = curr.next.next

            curr.next = b
            a.next = b.next
            b.next = a
            curr = a

        return dummy.next
```

The confusion:

When I do `curr = dummy` , it seems that dummy is passed by reference and mutating `curr` mutates `dummy`. But the return statement `return dummy.next` is not the same value as `return curr.next`? Since `curr = dummy`, at the end of the loop, `curr` is at the end of the list, so shouldn't `dummy` also be at the end of the list? However, `dummy` is still at the very front of the list and `dummy.next` is the start of the list passed into the function but mutated in the correct way.

Also, when I do:

```
        if curr is dummy:
            print("BEGIN")

        while curr.next and curr.next.next:
            a = curr.next
            b = curr.next.next

            curr.next = b
            a.next = b.next
            b.next = a
            curr = a

        if curr is dummy:
            print("END")
```

`BEGIN` gets printed but `END` doesn't.

Can someone clear the confusion up for me?

Comment: `curr` is the same as `dummy` initially, yes, but you set `curr = a` inside the loop, so `curr` won't remain the same as `dummy`.  You're setting it to something else.  Search this site for many, many questions about Python value/reference, variables, name binding, etc.

Comment: **there is no pass-by-reference semantics in Python**.

Comment: Please read [Ned Batchelder's Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do an assignment `var = x` you make `var` point to `x`. It wouldn't make other variables pointed to the same object point to `x` after this.

Consider this example:

```
>>> a = {'p': 2}
>>> b = a
>>> b
{'p': 2}
>>> b['p'] = 4
>>> a
{'p': 4}
>>> b = {'q': 3}
>>> a
{'p': 4}
>>> b
{'q': 3}
```

Or this:

```
>>> class Node:
...     def __init__(self, nxt):
...         self.nxt = nxt
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '(Node => %s)' % self.nxt
... 
>>> a = Node(Node(2))
>>> a
(Node => (Node => 2))
>>> b = a
>>> b
(Node => (Node => 2))
>>> a.nxt = Node(4)
>>> a
(Node => (Node => 4))
>>> b
(Node => (Node => 4))
>>> b = b.nxt
>>> a
(Node => (Node => 4))
>>> b
(Node => 4)
```